# Trigger popup to open in mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, popup, popupmenu

I am using a popup plugin to generate leads and I am targeting a specific menu to open popup on click however it is working in desktop and not working in mobile.

This is my jQuery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.menu-item-10484').find('a').attr('data-target', 'paoc-pro-modal-10420');
jQuery('.menu-item-10484').find('a').addClass('paoc-pro-popup paoc-pro-popup-button');
```

});

Comment: if your design is responsive , you need to make sure that the *div* with this *class* 

menu-item-10484 actually have this class on mobile version ,

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada Yes the class is also there in the Responsive as well.

Comment: im 100% sure its not an query issue its css issue 
check if the pop up actually shows in the dom when the window is minimized

Comment: @IbraHimM.NadaThe popup content is there but it is not getting activated when click on menu item in Mobile hamburger menu.